# How to disable Amazon S3 raw endpoint access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Say you want to host a static web site on S3 :

1. You create a bucket with name `your-website.com` and set it up for web hosting;
2. You add a CNAME in your domain's zone file to point to your S3 bucket.

Great. Everything works fine when you visit `http://your-website.com`. But you don't want the raw/"naked" endpoint to be accessible.

Is there any setting in the bucket to disable direct access to `http://your-website.com.s3-website.your-region.amazonaws.com` ?

The reason is that if your web site is accessible both through `http://your-website.com` and `http://your-website.com.s3-website.your-region.amazonaws.com` would hurt your SEO (duplicate content)

Comment: Not sure this is possible.  Have you read the docs on [website endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html) and [virtual hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html)?

From the former:  
"Website Endpoint - Access control - Supports only publicly readable content."

Comment: Yes, but could not find any "clue" about this. May be this could be possible by throwing some cloudfront in the mix...

Comment: Indeed, CloudFront would do : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

Comment: Would this only allow Cloudfront to access S3 through the REST API and not the website API?  The website endpoint has more features (object level redirect, html bodies on 404s, etc.).

Comment: @redben, would you mind explaining a bit more *why* you want to do that? Also, what exactly do you mean by *disable* (403? 404? 50x? 30x? 200 with error page? no DNS resolution?...)

Comment: Well may be a permanent redirect. The reason you'd want to disable raw endpoint access is mainly duplicate content on search engines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mention your major concern is SEO. For that purpose, you could use a other techniques, that are probably easier to implement than the one you initially asked about.

One of the main techniques to deal with duplicate content is to use `rel=canonical`, which is probably fairly easy to implement. For more information, see http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html

If you insist on the need to disable access to the bucket unless the client connects through your CNAME, your best bet is to use CloudFront. You disable the S3 website hosting option on your bucket, make your S3 bucket private (i.e., remove bucket policies or ACLs allowing public read), create a CloudFront distribution, define your bucket as the origin, configure a CNAME on your distribution, change your DNS records to point to your distribution instead of bucket, create an **Origin Access Identity (OAI)** on your distribution and grant access to your bucket for that OAI. Phew.

By doing all this, there's no way for a user to access the content on your S3 bucket (unless they have an AK/SK with permissions to read the bucket, and send a signed request, obviously). The only way will be through your domain.

For more detail on **Origin Access Identity**, see **http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html**

Comment: Thanks actually that's what I did, cloudFront. But then I hit a problem, my bucket is in the new Frankfurt location which only support v4 authentication (cloudFront does not use that). So I'm moving my bucket to one of the older locations

Comment: For the rel canonical, it was not an option since I can't guarantee the webmaster sticks to that rule...

Comment: I'm not sure how to complete the steps from `define your bucket as the origin` - would someone be able to clarify what this means? Thanks.

Comment: @fuzzi - the "Getting Started with CloudFront" documentation page shows how to `define your bucket as the origin` step by step. Check that out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html . Cheers!